# Duplicate Rows in a Pandas DataFrame and replacing values by multiple other values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First of all, hi everyone! This is the first time I am actually posting a question on StackOverflow, so if I am too specific / too general, I would appreciate receiving advise :).

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing some SAP Authorization Data, in which a column can contain something like "placeholder values" which shall be resolved to their corresponding values. And at this point, I really run out of Ideas..

For Example, in the DataFrame shown below I have two Roles, each containing the (authorization) object `F_BKPF_BUK` with the Fields `ACTVT` and `ABC`. `ABC` is characterized with the "placeholder value" `$EKGRP` for `LOW`.

```py
                   ROLE        OBJECT    FIELD     LOW HIGH
0  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A    F_BKPF_BUK    ACTVT      03  NaN
1  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A    F_BKPF_BUK      ABC  $EKGRP  NaN
2  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B    F_BKPF_BUK    ACTVT      03  NaN
3  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B    F_BKPF_BUK      ABC  $EKGRP  NaN
```

Now, the tricky thing is, that the placeholder `$EKGRP` usually resolves to role dependent (!) *multiple values*. The DataFrame for $EKGRP is as follows:

```python
                   ROLE   VARBL  LOW HIGH
0  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A  $EKGRP  U01  U99
1  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A  $EKGRP  P01  P99
2  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A  $EKGRP  P01  P29
3  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B  $EKGRP  P01  P00
4  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B  $EKGRP  N01  N99
5  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B  $EKGRP  I01  I99
```

So the final result I would like to achieve is to substitute all occurrences of a placeholder with  its corresponding values for both columns `LOW` and `HIGH`:

```python
                   ROLE        OBJECT    FIELD     LOW HIGH
0  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A    F_BKPF_BUK    ACTVT      03  NaN
1  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A    F_BKPF_BUK      ABC     U01  U99
2  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A    F_BKPF_BUK      ABC     P01  P99
3  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A    F_BKPF_BUK      ABC     P01  P29
4  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B    F_BKPF_BUK    ACTVT      03  NaN
5  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B    F_BKPF_BUK      ABC     P01  P00
6  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B    F_BKPF_BUK      ABC     N01  N99
7  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B    F_BKPF_BUK      ABC     I01  I99
```

Started using Pandas only a few weeks ago, I soon reached a point where I ran out of ideas for this particular problem. My latest guess was to maybe use `df.apply(...)` to check for a placeholder, but this approach would not solve the issue that, once a placeholder is found, the original line has to be duplicated several times with their `LOW` and `HIGH` values getting changed to the corresponding values.
Which pandas function would you recommend me to take a closer look at? I would like to avoid row-by-row iterations as far as possible and get to know the "best practices" for those kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible use outer join by column `LOW` from `df1` with `ROLE` first copy `LOW` to `VARBL` in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then replace missing values in [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) (necessary remove `_` in columns for match) and last remove unnecesary columns:

```
df = (df1.assign(VARBL = df1['LOW'])
         .merge(df2, on=['ROLE','VARBL'], how='outer', suffixes=('_','')))

df[['LOW','HIGH']] = (df[['LOW','HIGH']].fillna(df[['LOW_','HIGH_']]
                                                  .rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_'))))
df = df.drop(['LOW_','HIGH_','VARBL'], axis=1)
print (df)
                   ROLE      OBJECT  FIELD  LOW HIGH
0  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A  F_BKPF_BUK  ACTVT   03  NaN
1  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A  F_BKPF_BUK    ABC  U01  U99
2  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A  F_BKPF_BUK    ABC  P01  P99
3  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_A  F_BKPF_BUK    ABC  P01  P29
4  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B  F_BKPF_BUK  ACTVT   03  NaN
5  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B  F_BKPF_BUK    ABC  P01  P00
6  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B  F_BKPF_BUK    ABC  N01  N99
7  D:AS:MY_FANCY_ROLE_B  F_BKPF_BUK    ABC  I01  I99
```